# SignalR .NET Client Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr

I'm using the `Credentials` property of the `HubConnection` class to pass the necessary id and password of a user/client.

My problem is that I need to validate the credentials not from within the server but another client designated as the `Provider` how can I forward the credentials from the server to another client for validation?

I understand what it must sound like but it is needed.

Suggestions on authenticating a client through the server calling another client to do the authentication are welcome.

Comment: Mark the message with some kind of Rule / Role etc and validate on server?

Comment: Would it be possible to have your Hub accept the connection, then call out to authenticate and then accept/deny and continue normal operation? Also, you can add information to the Header of the SignalR messages, depending how you authenticate you may need to specify a header.

Comment: @Tony indeed that is acceptable, though I would like to use standard authentication methods built into SignalR if at all possible

Comment: @ReeganLayzell check this link. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization Search for Customize Authorization you can probably hook into that approach and pass it off to the other server and then deny or accept.

Comment: @Tony There doesn't seem to be any way to pass/retrieve the client credentials with a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` derived type or any access to other clients on the hub.

Comment: @ReeganLayzell, check 2 code samples down from that one. In the OnConnected() method they call a GetAuthInfo protected method. You could use a similar approach. You should have access to the context of the message and be able to retrieve a specified header. I have no worked directly with the Credential property but check your message from the client and see what header property it is binding to and set up your custom auth off those. You can have it check if they are already authenticated and if not send off to the other server and then pass the token back and forth.